# Build custom LineageOS ROM for device based on RK3399 processor

Tags: android, linux, device-tree, custom-rom, lineageos

I have to build a custom ROM based on lineage and make it run on a device that is based on the Rockchip RK3399. After doing some research I figured that I need:

- the kernel source for the specific device
- device tree
- device vendor files

I found a kernel source https://github.com/rockchip-linux/kernel. However, I cannot find a device tree and device vendor files. Is there any chance of getting lineage running on a device like this? I'm really new to android dev. and I am primarily looking for an estimate of how likely it is to get lineage running on a device like this.

Comment: I would recommend you to check out XDA forums, there the number of people with rom development skills is significant larger than here. For device tree see e.g. https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-how-to-make-a-device-tree-for-your-phone.3698419/